# Generic class call that have parameters

Tags: c#

In my form1 I have this method.

```
public void ChangeView<T>() where T : Control, new()
    {
        if (transitionManager1.IsTransition)
        {
            transitionManager1.EndTransition();
        }

        transitionManager1.StartTransition(BasePanel);
        try
        {

            T find = Find<T>(BasePanel);
            if (find != null)
            {
                find.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                find = new T();
                find.Parent = BasePanel;
                find.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                find.BringToFront();
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            transitionManager1.EndTransition();
        }
    }
```

the problem is when I'm trying to call this method from user control named userC1 that have some parameters in constructor like below

```
Form1 f;
    public UserC1(Form1 f)   
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.f = f;
    }
```

I call the method as follows in form 1

```
ChangeView<UserC1>();
```

but above code is an error it says 
must be a non abstract type with public parameter less constructor in order to use it a parameter  in the generic type or method.

how can I over come from this problem.
I need that parameters in userC1 constructor.

Comment: Well what do you expect `find = new T()` to do in `ChangeView`, if `T` is `UserC1`?

Comment: You explicitly require a parameterless constructor via the `new()` in the signature.  However, if you remove that, how would you imagine calling a constructor with different signatures?  How would you know that e.g. a `Foo` has a parameterless constructor, but a `Bar` requires params?  You can't, and now you don't have a generic function.  If you need a reference to the parent form why not just use `Control.Parent`?

Answer (score 0):

I edit the code as follows and add a interface to my code as follows:

```
T Find<T>(Control container) where T : Control
{
    for (int i = 0; i < container.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (container.Controls[i] is T)
        {
            return (T)container.Controls[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void ChangeView<T>(Func<INavigationControl, T> createTInstance) where T : Control, new()
{
    if (transitionManager1.IsTransition)
    {
        transitionManager1.EndTransition();
    }

    transitionManager1.StartTransition(BasePanel);
    try
    {
        T find = Find<T>(BasePanel);
        if (find != null)
        {
            find.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            if (createTInstance == null)
                find = new T();
            else
                find = createTInstance(this);
            find.Parent = BasePanel;
            find.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            find.BringToFront();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        transitionManager1.EndTransition();
    }
}

public interface INavigationControl
{
    void ChangeView<T>(Func<INavigationControl, T> createTInstance) where T : Control, new();
}
```

then I added this code to call my change view method

```
ChangeView<Configurationn>(form => new Configurationn(form));
```

to do this we have to edit the constructor as follows.

```
INavigationControl1 f1;
public YourForm(INavigationControl1 f1) :this(){
    this.f1 = f1;
}
```